# What value of inductance and type of inductor should i choose for my motor driver circuit?

Tags: dc-motor, inductor, h-bridge, motor-controller, high-current

I am current design a DC motor driver circuit for 24 volts and 50 amperes since the motors I am using take 25 amperes nominally. I will be using PWM signal to control the output. I was suggested to add a inductor in series with the main 24 volt because it will reduce the inrush peak current as well as any other noise. 
Kindly suggest the appropriate inductor type and a way to calculate proper inductance value.
Furthermore, any guidance regarding the safety and design will be very helpful.

ps: I am using mosfets ir3205 and driver ir2103 as basic components. If there are any better and cheap components availabe, please tell.

Comment: WHat is the biggest inductive load switch you have successfully built so far?  Have you not done any homework to compute Ron DCR and losses?  What are your design specs?  THis is hopeless without them.  Inrush could be as much as 250A (?)

Comment: Draw your schematic.

Comment: What frequency is the PWM? What is supplying the 24V? Do you plan to include current limiting or regenerative braking? Is the controller unidirectional, or bidirectional (H bridge)?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, I designed a circuit for 10 amps which worked fine. But that was for my personal project, so I didnt had any regard for the safety. Kindly clarify, what details do you require for design specs, DCR and Ron?

Comment: @Andyaka it is done and I have tested the ciruit up to 22 amps. It is working fine, But it has no safeties like current limiting, or blocking inrush current, etc

Comment: Sir @BruceAbbott  PWM frequency is about 1khz, it will be using LiPo or lead acid battery to supply 24 volt. I need to include current limiting but not regenerative braking. It is a H-bridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you say:-

> PWM frequency is about 1khz, it will be using LiPo or lead acid
>   battery

Battery-powered speed controllers don't usually bother with inductive filters.

Inductance in the power supply leads is bad because it causes voltage spikes. Large low ESR bulk capacitors are usually added across the controller power input to reduce spikes. These will cause a high surge current when power is applied, but the battery can handle it. If this surge current is a problem for the connectors or power switch then a two stage connection sequence can be applied, with the first stage going through a small value resistor to limit capacitor charging current.

With 1kHz PWM the FET Gate drive current can be reduced to increase switching times and reduce high frequency EMI, if that is a problem. If several FETs are wired in parallel they should have individual Gate resistors to minimize ringing.

> I am using mosfets ir3205 and driver ir2103 as basic components.  If
>   there are any better and cheap components availabe, please tell.

IR3205 is OK for this application. You will need 2 in parallel per H-bridge leg (8 total) to handle 25 A continuous / 50 A peak current. With lower resistance FETs (eg. 2 mΩ) you might get away with 1 FET per leg, which could be cheaper depending on unit cost and other factors (PCB area, heat sink size etc.).

IR2103 is a good half-bridge driver, and they are cheap enough that price should not be an issue. However be aware that you cannot get 100% PWM out of it unless you use an isolated DC/DC converter to supply the upper FET Gate drive voltage.